# How to ban message author in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a function that has a 0.01 percent chance of banning you. But I can't seem to find a way to ban the author of the message.
Here's what I have tried - `message.author.ban()`

Comment: Maybe this link from the Discord Documentation will help you
[Discord : how do I ban a user? ](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-ban-a-user)

Answer (score 3):

`message.author` returns a user object - this is the information about an account not connected to the server it is in. To get the member object, you can do `message.member` - this gives you the member of the server and you can add roles, change nickname, kick, ban and more on this.
The correct way is `message.member.ban()`.